# Sort problem with date diffs for leap year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pick up some work that someone else has done which for the most part does work apart from when leap years are concerned. The below SQL is in an existing report but returns the value as 37 months when run for the periods show in the SQL. If these dates change to 2020 - 2023, it correctly shows 36 months as there was no leap year in that period. The period of 2023-2026 does have a leap year in 2024. Could anyone advise please. Keeping the code below as close to the original as possible would be great as I need to put this back into a larger piece for a report that runs the SQL.

```sql
select case 
    when ('01/06/2020' ='' AND '31/05/2023' ='') 
    then 'N/A'
    else
'01/06/2020' + ' to ' + '31/05/2023' + ' (' + cast( convert(int, round(datediff(d,convert(datetime,'01/06/2020',103),convert(datetime,'31/05/2023',103))/30.0, 0)) AS varchar) + ' months )' end
```

This is the current SQL

```
select case 
    when ('01/06/2020' ='' AND '31/05/2023' ='') 
    then 'N/A'
    else
    '01/06/2020' + ' to ' + '31/05/2023' + ' (' + cast( convert(int, round(datediff(d,convert(datetime,'01/06/2020',103),convert(datetime,'31/05/2023',103))/30.0, 0)) AS varchar) + ' months )' end
```

Comment: I've removed all the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question the tag what you are really using, and just that

Comment: Please update your question with the full SQL statement you are trying to run, the table definitions and explain what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: At first glace: I see you are dividing by 30.0, which is a very rough length of the average month in days. Maybe just divide by a more exact number, like 30.44 instead?

Comment: "Brilliant" code. Rounding discards the days left over by pretending a month is always 30 days... as long as there are not too many of them. (3 years x 5 extra days per year is exactly 0.5 pretend-months.) @shaun, will this code never be used with periods longer than 36 months? Because say 40 months will have too many extra days even if you pick a period that does not include a leap-year February.

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner, that seems to work but I shall do some more testing

Comment: Thanks @alexis, Im facing this issue in an existing report which details contract lengths, which I dont believe will ever be above 3 years

Comment: If you want the number of months, why just `DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate,DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate))`?

Comment: Very strange that you are mixing `cast` and `convert`. Note you should never `cast` to `varchar` without specifying the size of the `varchar`.

Comment: @DaleK The entry in the post give the whole query and explains both the expected and actual results.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a built in function to calculate the time difference between the two dates.
As Thom A and Vishal Hadawale already suggested use DATEDIFF.

But I think you can throw away the CASE in your query as it will always go to the else, because '01/06'2020' can never be equal to ''.

As you've mentioned that the expected result is 36 as the difference is 35 Months 30 Days.

If you want every month to count as full:
(e.g. 02/05/2023 counts the same as 31/05/2023)

```sql
DECLARE @start_date date = CONVERT(DATE, '01/06/2020', 103);
DECLARE @end_date date = CONVERT(DATE, '31/05/2023', 103); 
SET @end_date = DATEADD(month,1,@end_date); 

SELECT DATEDIFF(month,@start_date,@end_date) as "DirectDatediff"; --Result: 36
```

If only end_dates from the 15th upward should count:

```sql
DECLARE @start_date date = CONVERT(DATE, '01/06/2020', 103);
DECLARE @end_date date = CONVERT(DATE, '31/05/2023', 103); 
--SET @end_date = DATEADD(month,1,@end_date); --use if every started month counts fully

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@start_date,@end_date) as 'NoLeapYear in days'; --Result: 1094
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@start_date,@end_date)/30 'NoLeapYear in months' ; --Result: 36

SET @start_date = CONVERT(DATE, '01/06/2023', 103);
SET @end_date = CONVERT(DATE, '31/05/2026', 103); 

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@start_date,@end_date) as 'LeapYear in days' ;--Result: 1095
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@start_date,@end_date)/30 as 'LeapYear in months'; --Result: 36

SELECT DATEDIFF(month,@start_date,@end_date) as "DirectDatediff"; --Result: 35

SELECT '' + Cast(@start_date as varchar) + ' to ' + CAST(@end_date as varchar) + ' (' + CAST(DATEDIFF(day,@start_date,@end_date)/30 as varchar) + ' Months)' ; 
-- Result: 2020-06-01 to 2023-05-31 (36 Months)
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9YKxkXLM)

Comment: I don't even think the nonsense with 30-day months in the code the OP found is intentional; so, short answer: Use `DATEDIFF(month, @start_date, @end_date)` which will return the number of months as calculated by database logic.